# Найдите количество палиндромов в массиве слов

Tags: javascript

Палиндром - слово, которое читается одинаково справа налево и слева направо. Дан массив, содержащий некоторое количество слов. Найдите количество элементов массива, которые являются палиндромами.

Напишите функцию с именем countPalindrome, которая принимает массив слов arr в качестве аргумента и возвращает количество слов, являющихся палиндромами. Использовать метод reverse() в этом задании не разрешено.

Примеры работы функции:

```
countPalindrome(["abc", "dad", "noon"]) // 2
countPalindrome(["mum"]) // 1
countPalindrome(["mother"]) // 0
countPalindrome([]) // 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function isPalindrome(str) {
    const length = str.length;
    const mid = Math.floor(length/2);
    
    for ( var i = 0; i < mid; i++ ) {
        if (str[i] !== str[length - 1 - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

function countPalindrome(arr) {
  return arr.filter(item => isPalindrome(item)).length
}

console.log(countPalindrome(["abc", "dad", "noon"]))
console.log(countPalindrome(["mum"]))
console.log(countPalindrome(["mother"]))
console.log(countPalindrome([]))
```

Вариант через цикл `for`:

```
function countPalindrome(arr) {
  const counter = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(isPalindrome(arr[i])) {
      counter.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return counter.length
}
```

Вариант через цикл `forEach`:

```
function countPalindrome(arr) {
  const counter = [];
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(isPalindrome(item)) {
      counter.push(item)
    }
  })
  return counter.length
}
```

Comment: а как же `split.reverse.join`? )

Comment: @teran по условию *Использовать метод reverse() в этом задании не разрешено.* )

Comment: аа, да. не дочитал )

Comment: Подскажите, как решить данную задачу через вложенные циклы(сравнивая побуквенно каждый элемент(строку)?

Comment: @MaryK если я правильно понял, думаю проблема в том что используется метод `filter`. Я добавил в ответ другой способ, возможно вам такой подойдет

Comment: Спасибо!!все работает.